# Trigger IBAction Or a Method with Tap Go/Enter Button in Virtual Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

With Text Box , whenever we tap Go button in virtual Keyboard , i wist call a Method , Any Suggestions How

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch the return key with the method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    /* call whatever methods you need */
    return YES;
}
```

But first, your view controller needs to be set as the textField's delegate.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html